# How to create API in laravel in route file

Tags: php, api, laravel-6

I'm trying to create a route in the api.php file in laravel 6, I'm returning a simple array just for testing, but it always gives an error, in the web.php routes file it works normally, but in the api.php file it doesn't work

```
Object { message: "", exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException", file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php", line: 179, trace: (21) […] }
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException"
file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php"
line: 179
message: ""
trace: Array(21) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
0: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", line: 635, function: "match", … }
​​1: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", line: 624, function: "findRoute", … }
​​2: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", line: 613, function: "dispatchToRoute", … }
​​3: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php", line: 170, function: "dispatch", … }
​​4: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 130, function: "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}", … }
​​5: Object { file: "/var/www/app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php", line: 18, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​6: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 171, function: "handle", … }
​​7: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php", line: 21, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​8: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 171, function: "handle", … }
​​9: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php", line: 21, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​10: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 171, function: "handle", … }
​​11: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php", line: 27, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​12: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 171, function: "handle", … }
​​13: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php", line: 63, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​14: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 171, function: "handle", … }
​​15: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php", line: 57, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​16: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 171, function: "handle", … }
​​17: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", line: 105, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
​​18: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php", line: 145, function: "then", … }
​​19: Object { file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php", line: 110, function: "sendRequestThroughRouter", … }
​​20: Object
```

Code Route:

```
Route::get('/api-teste',
    ['uses' => 'RegisterController@show']
);
```

Code Controller:

```
public function show()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'nome' => 'paulo',
            'genero' => 'masculino',
        ]);
    }
```

I already tried with route resource and also, clear the cache

```
sudo docker exec -it phpgold-app php artisan optimize'
```

OBS: I'm using docker container, but it works perfectly in the web.php file

Comment: if in web.php, you can access with /api-teste, but if in api.php you can access /api/api-teste

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) , silly error, how do I format the error like you formatted above? I'm new here in posting.

Comment: check in down your post, this lagbox edited your post, select your code and ctrl + K to format your code